# OpenCV stereo calibration error - (-3:Internal error) CALIB_CHECK_COND - Ill-conditioned matrix for input array 1 in function 'CalibrateExtrinsics'

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, stereoscopy

opencv version is 3.4.9

I use this [code](https://github.com/realizator/stereopi-fisheye-robot/blob/master/4_calibration_fisheye.py)  to calibrate. My stereoscopic camera consists of two GoPro Session cameras (with settings - 1080p 30 fps, medium angle) fixed on an aluminium plane 90 cm away from each other, also used a wifi remote controller for the cameras to be in sync. I shot a 2 minute video covering every angel of both cameras, I used my TV screen as the board (I needed it to be big because the cameras are too far away from each other), and I broke down the video into frames, also I deleted all the frames where the algorithm couldn't find the chessboard (if one of the cameras can't find the pattern that exact frame was deleted from both cameras). When testing the undistortion with using that 9x6 chessboard pattern I noticed that every picture looks horrible after undistortion

[image]

here's the original. I tried everything, with light, with printed board on the paper and glued to a flat board, every time undistorded image looks like this

[image]

and many times it looks worse than this, and also it's worth to mention that i resize the images from 1920x1080 to 640x360 before undistorting the image.

The main problem is that I get this error every time I run that code from github

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.9) /io/opencv/modules/calib3d/src/fisheye.cpp:1421: error: (-3:Internal error) CALIB_CHECK_COND - Ill-conditioned matrix for input array 1 in function 'CalibrateExtrinsics'
```

and I have zero idea what to do. I think that bad undistortion problem causes this error, or am I wrong?? Please tell me what to do.

Comment: The first image is the original fisheye image, and second one is after the undistortion?

Comment: yes @IbrahimYousuf

Comment: What if you skip the undistortion part?

Comment: I need to make a stereo camera that will calculate depth, how can I do that without undistortion?? @IbrahimYousuf

Answer (score 4):

So the error is raised here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/fisheye.cpp#L1421 when evaluating the vector of singular values `w` output from Singular Value Decomposition (`SVD`). Specifically, the ratio of the first singular value and the last singular value (`svd.w.at<double>(0) / svd.w.at<double>((int)svd.w.total() - 1)`) exceed a threshold value (in this case, `1e6`, based on the variable `thresh_cond`).

It looks like you can configure whether this condition (`check_cond`) is evaluated using `CALIB_CHECK_COND` (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/fisheye.cpp#L740), which can be provided in the `stereoCalibrate` function: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d58/group__calib3d__fisheye.html#gadbb3a6ca6429528ef302c784df47949b. The `stereoCalibrate` function is called at this [line](https://github.com/realizator/stereopi-fisheye-robot/blob/master/4_calibration_fisheye.py#L252) in the script you're using; you'll just have to change `cv2.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC` to `cv2.fisheye.CALIB_CHECK_COND`.

Hope this helps, or at least gets you some results!

## Update

After changing the flag from `cv2.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC` to `cv2.fisheye.CALIB_CHECK_COND`, a new error is raised due to a failed assertion: `(-215:Assertion failed) abs_max < threshold in function 'stereoCalibrate'`. This assertion occurs here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/fisheye.cpp#L1023. A quick google search yields these two questions from the OpenCV question forum:

- https://answers.opencv.org/question/213931/assertion-failed-abs_max-threshold-in-function-stereocalibrate/

  - https://answers.opencv.org/question/67855/opencv-error-assertion-failed-abs_max-threshold-in-stereocalibrate/

Both of which conclude the same thing: in the sets of images they were using, there were some bad stereo pairs that needed to be removed. Also, in the line from the source code, there is a single comment above the assertion when computing `abs_max`: `//check goodness of stereopair` (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/fisheye.cpp#L1013).

One of the answers in the OpenCV forums from recently (March 2020), had some logic to check for bad stereo pairs: https://answers.opencv.org/question/213931/assertion-failed-abs_max-threshold-in-function-stereocalibrate/?answer=227486#post-id-227486

In the script your using, I think it would translate to adding these lines [here](https://github.com/realizator/stereopi-fisheye-robot/blob/master/4_calibration_fisheye.py#L111):

```
    diff = cornersL - cornersR
    lengths = np.linalg.norm(diff[:, :, 1], axis=-1)
    sum = np.sum(lengths, axis=0)
    if (sum > 2000.0):
        print(f"THIS STEREO PAIR IS BROKEN!!! Diff is: {sum}")
        cornersR = np.flipud(cornersR)
```

Alternatively, you could just `continue` if that condition is met, and skip those pairs altogether (although I'm not sure if that would be ideal). You may also want to print/save the names of the images (`leftName`) and (`rightName`) so you can inspect them - although at that point, I would recommend just adding a breakpoint where the check occurs and step through to evaluate in real time.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'CALIB_CHECK_COND'

Comment: Ah sorry! The flag is actually located in the `fisheye` module, so it would be  `cv2.fisheye.CALIB_CHECK_COND`. Correcting my answer now.

Comment: (-215:Assertion failed) abs_max < threshold in function 'stereoCalibrate'

now this error

Comment: Just added an update in the answer with some new thoughts/ideas.

Answer (score 0):

the undistorted image should be in the same size as those in your calibration, unless you did some modification to the calibration parameters

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).